# MPI: BLCR kernel module not present

Tags: parallels, mpi

how can I remove the bug of MPI in Ubuntu

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Init_thread: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(474)...: 
MPID_Init(190)..........: channel initialization failed
MPIDI_CH3_Init(89)......: 
MPID_nem_init(413)......: 
MPIDI_nem_ckpt_init(170): BLCR kernel module not present
Fatal error in PMPI_Init_thread: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(474)...: 
MPID_Init(190)..........: channel initialization failed
MPIDI_CH3_Init(89)......: 
MPID_nem_init(413)......: 
MPIDI_nem_ckpt_init(170): BLCR kernel module not present
```

I have installed BLCR in Ubuntu.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: It is installed, but is it loaded? Add the output of `lsmod | grep -i blcr` to your question. You also might want to try `modprobe blcr`.

Comment: @Thomas, Thanks a lot for your answer! If I use "modprobe blcr", then I get the infos: modprobe: FATAL: Module blcr not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic

Comment: What makes you think it is installed?

Comment: @MadMike, em, the software worked at the last month, after update of ubuntu, it does not work... I do not uninstall BLCR (at least I can remember that)...